# Facebook App Review upload apk file issue

Tags: android, facebook

It was never in vain to integrate Facebook into Android Apps but now things seem to be complicated in a way ,may be to get more secure social media.
That's good though .

The Problem what am having is with the Submit Approval Process . i am unable to upload the .apk file in my application as my file size exceeds 100MB. when i upload the .apk file in zip form on dropbox and shared the download link/Url to facebook , it says that MIME/TYPE should be in application/zip.

I have tried following scenarios but no Success:

1) Uploading .apk single file on my dropbox then using its downloadable link.

2) Uploading .zip file containing only .apk file int on my dropbox then using its downloadable link.

3) Uploading .rar file containing only .apk file int on my dropbox then using its downloadable link.

I cannot go for the second option of submitting the app to google play store as my App is Paid App there and Unlike iPhone ,Google does not support for Promo codes but Facebook needs promo-codes for paid app to download it from google play store .

Answer (score 0):

Can you reduce the APK size to <100MB?

Perhaps an other approach is to upload an empty APK, but make it clear in your comments that the real APK can be found on your Dropbox link. State that you are limited by upload size, but that the APK in the Dropbox link should be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this solution to reduce the APK size ? : 
In Android studio: **Refactor** -> **Remove Unused Resources**.